# Class Instantiation - Polymorphism - Python

Tags: python, class, instantiation

I used the following code

```
class FooBar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0

    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
```

I save the above in `FooBar.py`

When I use,

```
import FooBar
p = FooBar()
```

The error says `module object not callable`. What is the reason?

Comment: Need `p = FooBar.FooBar()` or use `from FooBar import FooBar`.

Comment: Where did you save FooBar.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `FooBar` you are importing is the module, not the class.

Replace:

```
import FooBar
```

with:

```
from FooBar import FooBar
```

Or, if you prefer, use:

```
import FooBar
# First FooBar is the module, second is the class within the module.
p = FooBar.FooBar()
```

Comment: I don't know how pertinent this comment is, but remember that Python is not Java, you don't have to name modules after contained classes. Modules are logical groupings for functions and classes related to the same purpose. Also, modules should be named in lowercase (so that you can distinguish them from classes).

Answer (score 1):

Second `def` redeclare `__init__` method. In python you can't overload methods.

Comment: While your answer is generally true, this is not the source of the error. Simply, the second definition overwrites the first.

Comment: I think, it's answer for second answer from this user :)